# Fast Converting RenderTexture to Texture2D in Unity3D

Tags: c#, screenshot, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I have a screenshot preview at the end of the game's level.
When I am loading the screenshot, it makes game freeze for a moment.
What shall I do, so there would be no freeze, when I am loading that screenshot?
Here is mycode:

```
private IEnumerator ShowScreeshotPreview()
{
    screenshotTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.height, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    RenderTexture.active = Singletons.Get<SpecialEffectsHelper>().MainCharacterScript.GetComponent<GeneratorScript>().screenshotTexture;
    screenshotTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.height, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenshotTexture.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = null; //Added to avoid errors

    screenshotPrview.mainTexture = screenshotTexture;
    screenshotPreviewAnimator.SetBool("visible", true);
    screenshotLoaded = true;

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Why not use Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot.png"); ?

Comment: @joreldraw I need to load screenshot, not make it

Comment: I not understand what are you trying to do with your loop.
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
Coroutines not freeze the game, are you sure that is this script the causant?

Comment: @joreldraw it makes freeze less laggy